# How to implement working, custom key bindings in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In my `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` located in `Applications/Xcode/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/`, I have added three custom actions, as follows:

```
<key>Customized</key>
<dict>
    <key>Copy Paragraph</key>
    <string>setMark:, selectParagraph:, copy:, swapWithMark:</string>
    <key>New Line After Current</key>
    <string>selectParagraph:, moveToRight:, insertNewline:</string>
    <key>Cut Paragraph</key>
    <string>selectParagraph:, copy:, delete:</string>
</dict>
```

But when I assign these actions to key bindings in my **Preferences/Key Bindings**, I get the error sound when I attempt to use them. Here are the bindings:

```
Copy Paragraph:         ⇧⌘C
Cut Paragraph:          ⇧⌘X
New Line After Current: ⌘↩
```

I've already tried restarting Xcode. I appreciate any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about preferences and programming.

Comment: @uchuugaka Are you referring to the **keyboard-shortcuts** tag?

Comment: No, the content itself. This is really not about programming, although it is arguably declarative programming... :)

Comment: @uchuugaka Ahh okay. I've seen a bunch of posts on here about Xcode key bindings so I figured it wouldn't hurt trying.